# Rendering basic bar chart with core plot in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

I am trying to render a basic bar chart with this code:

```
    import UIKit
    import CorePlot

    class BarChart: CPTGraphHostingView, CPTPlotDataSource, CPTPlotDelegate, CPTPlotSpaceDelegate
    {
    let data: [[UInt]] = [
        [30, 40, 100],
        [10, 44, 35]
    ]

    func renderData() {
        let barGraph = CPTXYGraph(frame: self.bounds)
        self.hostedGraph = barGraph
        barGraph.axisSet = nil

        var space: CPTXYPlotSpace = barGraph.defaultPlotSpace as! CPTXYPlotSpace
        barGraph.addPlotSpace(space)
        space.yRange = CPTPlotRange(locationDecimal: CPTDecimalFromFloat(0), lengthDecimal: CPTDecimalFromFloat(50))
        space.xRange = CPTPlotRange(locationDecimal: CPTDecimalFromFloat(0), lengthDecimal: CPTDecimalFromFloat(3))
        space.delegate = self

        var bar = CPTBarPlot(frame: barGraph.bounds)
        bar.dataSource = self
        bar.barWidth = 3

        barGraph.addPlot(bar, toPlotSpace: space)
    }

    func numberForPlot(plot: CPTPlot, field: UInt, recordIndex: UInt ) -> AnyObject? {
        return data[0][Int(idx)]
    }

    func barFillForBarPlot(barPlot: CPTBarPlot, recordIndexRange indexRange: NSRange) -> AnyObject? {
        return CPTFill(color: CPTColor(componentRed: 0, green: 0, blue: 255, alpha: 1))
    }

    func numberOfRecordsForPlot(plot: CPTPlot) -> UInt {
        return 3
    }
    }
```

This class is associated with a view in storyboard.
Unfortunately, I can't manage to display any data (but axis are visible when i remove the line with `barGraph.axisSet = nil`). Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Check the function signature for the bar fill datasource method. It should be `-barFillsForBarPlot:recordIndexRange:` and return an `NSArray` of fills. Use `-barFillForBarPlot:recordIndex:` to return one fill at a time.

Answer (score 0):

When using Swift, I would recommend getting the version of Core Plot on the "release-2.0" branch from GitHub. It has some API changes to make working with Swift easier. The biggest one is offering alternatives to the methods and properties that use `NSDecimal` values, e.g., plot ranges. I hope to have release 2.0 done soon after Xcode 7 is final.

There's no need to add the default plot space to the graph; it's already there.

The `-numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:` function should return the value as an `NSNumber`. Cast the value when returning it, e.g., `return data[0][Int(idx)] as NSNumber`.